# Django Multiple chartJs chats in a page

Tags: python, html, django, chart.js

I am developing a Dashboard. I am having 3 html pages that have a chart in them like below. I am having 3 charts as i will be using the charts in other html pages throughout the django project. So i decided to have the charts in a different html pages and provide data from view.

#### Barchart1.html

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

#### Barchart2.html

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

#### Barchart3.html

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I want these charts to be displayed in master.html page and will provide data from dictionary. Is it possible and how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to return your dictionary from your view. like this..

```
votes_dict={'one':12,'two': 19,'three': 3,'four': 5,'five': 2,'six': 3}

return render(request, 'master.html',{'votes':votes_dict})
```

So the votes_dict is your dictionary and votes is just the name you will call it so you can reference it on your template.

Then on your template it will look something like this...

```
      {% block content %}
    
        {% if votes %}
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data:  [{{ votes.one }}, {{ votes.two }}, {{ votes.three }}, {{ votes.four }}, {{ votes.five }}, {{ votes.six }} ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

If your dictionary is bigger than one dimension it will look more like this

```
{% for vote in votes %}
   {{ vote.one }}, {{ vote.two }}, {{ vote.three }}, {{ vote.four }}, {{ vote.five }}, {{ vote.six }}

  {% endfor %}
       

          
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what if there are different types of charts like bar, line. How will the master  HTML look