# Django - display the same chart in loop in jinja template with chart.js

Tags: django, charts, jinja2

I would like to display the same chart (of course with different data and labels) in loop. At this moment I have:

```
 <tbody>
        {% for key, value in game_details.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.all }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.win }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.lost }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                    <script>
                        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'pie',
                            data: {
                                labels: ['Win', 'Lost'],
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: '# of Votes',
                                    data: [{{ value.win }}, {{ value.lost }}],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    ],
                                    borderColor: [
                                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    ],
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }]
                            },
                            options: {
                                scales: {
                                    y: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

The first chart is displayed, but when I'm looking in console I can see: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ctx' has already been declared (at (index):179:29)`. So my loop can't create another chart, because `ctx` is already declared. My goal is to display chart for each iteration over dictionary. I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423524/django-multiple-chartjs-chats-in-a-page), but it doesn't sole my problem. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your canvas identifier and those JavaScript constant names with the [loop index `loop.index`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for):

For example:

```
{% for key, value in game_details.items %}
  <canvas id="myChart{{ loop.index }}" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    const ctx{{ loop.index }} = document.
      getElementById('myChart{{ loop.index }}').
      getContext('2d');
    const myChart{{ loop.index }} = new Chart(ctx{{ loop.index }}, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: ['Win', 'Lost'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [{{ value.win }}, {{ value.lost }}],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
       }]
     },
     options: {
       scales: {
         y: {
           beginAtZero: true
         }
       }
     }
   });
 </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have a weird interaction. When I add `{{ loop.index }}` in 5 places (id, ctx, getElementById, myChart and new Chart) nothing changes. Only 1 chart is displayed. But when I change `{{ loop.index }}` to `{{ key }}`, the first chart isn't displayed, but others are

Comment: Inspect the generated code source and ensure there is no extra space and that the const are well `ctx1`, `ctx2`, `ctx3`, ... same for the id of the canvas, of the other JS const, etc.

Comment: Problem solved. One of my game had name `ping-pong`. Changing it to `pingpong` solved problem and all charts are displayed